# How to insert multiple product image by laravel?

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-blade

here is my html code form code.

```
<div class="form-group">
      <label >Product Image</label>
      <input type="file" class="form-control btn btn-primary" name="image[]" multiple="multiple">
</div>
```

Comment: Can you improve your question please ?

Comment: Please provide more details about exact code that is not working, what solutions have you tried as well as what is it exactly that you are uncertain about. Currently you did not provide enough context to provide any meaningful answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use like this in your laravel controller file

**in controller**

```
$productSubImages = $request->file('sub_image');
       foreach($productSubImages as $productSubImage){
           $subImageName =$productSubImage->getClientOriginalName();
           $subImageDirectory = 'product-sub-images/';
           $productSubImage->move($subImageDirectory,$subImageName);
           $subImageUrl =$subImageDirectory.$subImageName;

           $subImage = new SubImage();
           $subImage->product_id = $productId;
           $subImage->sub_image = $subImageUrl;
           $subImage->save();
       }
```